# Removing .html for index file in subfolder

Tags: html

I have just launched an English version of my website, adding an index.html file to an /en subfolder.

Now, I cannot access produktionskollektivet.com/en/ (it returns a 403 Forbidden), but have to link to produktionskollektivet.com/en/index.html.

I have a Rewrite rule in .htaccess that should remove the .html extension, but that doesn't seem to work in this instance.

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
Redirect 301 /hej-hbg.html /index.html
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Removing .html extension using .htaccess file:**

```html
DirectoryIndex somepage.php home.php welcome.php index.html index.php landingpage.html
```

~Put there where you want to remove the extension.

**Note:** save the file with the *.htaccess* extension.

This is easy & works for me, Hope it helps.